# How to load image in post change in Oracle Developer 6i?

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, jdeveloper

I am kind of new in **Oracle Developer 6i 10g** .

I want to show image (`datatype Long Raw`) in a non-database field based on post change trigger.

I have attached the trigger that I use on book_id in my form

```
    SELECT BP.IMAGE INTO :BK_PIX
FROM BOOKS B, BOOKS_PIC BP
WHERE BP.ID# = B.ID#
AND B.ID# = :BOOK_ID;
```

But it gives me the following error:

[image]

Can you guide me, and explain to me what I am doing wrong here. 
Is there a way to achieve my expected result.

Last but not least, BK_PIC field does exist with image type. 
its a non-database field.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that an APEX form?

Comment: No, its not an Apex form.